# The Xamarin account is not activated

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

When you log in to my account Xamarin shows an error message:

```
 (Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path '', line 0, position 0.)[enter image description here][1]
```

[image]

Comment: Looks like you're getting a HTML/XML response where you should be getting a JSON object. Anyhow, I think your best bet is to contact Xamarin support

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that xamarin.com redirects to https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/xamarin/. I think that this is the root cause. Subdomains like forums.xamarin.com and blog.xamarin.com are still working.